# Interaction between CGI-Webserver and C++ code

Tags: c++, webserver, cgi

I have a c++ code on a robot infrastructure. I would like to make a web-UI that is accessible via the robots WiFi shield. I have never done this before so i have some questions.

- Is there a way to have my c++ code directly interact with the cgi of the
  website or do i need to use intermediary files?
- Would i have to start both the cgi and the c++ code or can i start the cgi code from my c++ program?
- Is there an alternative to compiling as cgi? Like maybe having the interface open directly in the c++ code?

I am sure this is a duplicate, but i didnt find anything, so any hint is appreciated!

---

Currently i have the c++ code send out html commands as string to the localhost,which works and i can see them in my browser. But it does not render as website, and just displays as html, probably because it is not compiled as cgi.

```
            pushCommand("HTTP / 1.1 200 OK\r\n");
            pushCommand("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
            pushCommand("Connection: close\r\n");
            // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
            pushCommand("Refresh: 5\r\n"); // refresh the page automatically every 5 sec
            pushCommand("\r\n");
            pushCommand("<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n");
            pushCommand("<html lang=\"en\">\r\n");
            pushCommand("\r\n");
            pushCommand("<html><head><title>CGI demo stage one</title></head>\r\n");
            pushCommand("<body><h1>CGI demo stage one</h1>\r\n");
            pushCommand("This program will calculate the average of some numbers<br>\r\n");
            pushCommand("<form action=cgidemo.cgi?step2 method=post>\r\n");
            pushCommand("  How many numbers would you like to enter? <input type=text name=number size=10><br>\r\n");
            pushCommand("  What is your favourite colour? <input type=text name=favcol size=20><br>\r\n");
            pushCommand("  <input type=submit value=\" DO IT \">\r\n");
            pushCommand("</form>\r\n");
            pushCommand("</body></html>\r\n");
```

where pushCommand(cmd) is basically a fifo implementation doing the following for every entry:

```
//doing this only once when the client is accepted
cout << "WEBUI Accepting client...\n" << endl;
int fd = accept(m_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &len);

//doing this for every entry of the fifo cue
cmd.copy(sendBuff, cmd.length());
sendBuff[cmd.length()] = 10;
n = send(fd, sendBuff, cmd.length() + 1, 0);
```